# Unable to view and access 'MSDN Platforms' subscription as Co-administrator in azure portal

Tags: azure, billing

I'm accessing 'MSDN Platforms' subscription as Co-administrator in Azure Powershell, but unable to view and access 'MSDN Platforms' subscription as Co-administrator in azure portal. need help in this regard.

[Azure Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWAet.png)

[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otbON.png)

Comment: maybe it is a different directory . did you check the drop down in the top right corner ?

Comment: Thank you. It is worked.

Comment: You could check on PowerShell, your subscriptions are not in one tenant.

Comment: Of-course tenants are different. Now I'm able to set the default subscription by the answered procedure to either of subscriptions. Thank you.

Comment: @SathishNit If you want to see your subscription in a directory, you should ensure your subscription in a same tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the drop-down list in the top right corner in **Azure Portal**:

[image]